# Unlist an structure of list of matrix in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have an object type list with a nested matrix on it, similar to the following example:

```
[[1]]
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]  A    A
[2,] A1   A2
[[2]]
    [,1]
[1,]  B 
[2,]  C
[[3]]
      NA
```

I need to unlist each matrix and pivot the results, as I need to get a data.frame with the following structure:

```
A   A1
A   A2
B   C
```

I tried to do it using an unlist function, but it unlist everything (also declaring the parameter recursive to False) and the result is:

```
A, A1, A2, B, C, NA
```

Apologizes because I don't have the code available at this moment and I can't paste a detailed example. When I'm at home I will update the message.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: after you did `unlist()` add a `matrix()` specifying the `ncol=` and `byrow=` argument

Comment: something similar to `matrix(unlist(df)[!is.na(unlist(df))], ncol = 2, byrow = T)` where df is your `list`

Answer (score 2):

```
L <- list(matrix(c("A", "A1", "A", "A2"), 2), matrix(c("B", "C"), ncol = 1), NA)

do.call(rbind, lapply(L, function(x) if (length(x) == 1L && is.na(x)) NULL else t(x)))
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "A"  "A1"
#[2,] "A"  "A2"
#[3,] "B"  "C
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It seems that the result fits perfectly with what I need!

I'll try it this evening with the real code and I update my answer.

Best regards.